# I want to split column data into Different column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i have data in a column which i want to split into different column.
data in column is not consistent.

eg:-

```
974/mt (ICD TKD)                                  
974/mt (+AD 91.27/mt, ICD/TKD)                    
970-980/mt                                        
970-980/mt
```

i have tried with substring but not found any solution

OUTPUT SHOULD BE:-

```
min  |max  | unit | description
-------------------------
NULL | 974 |  /mt | ICD TKD

NULL | 974  | /mt |+AD 91.27/mt, ICD/TKD

970  | 980  | /mt |NULL
```

Comment: What is the logic of extraction?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex to parse the information, and then add columns with the parsed data.

**Assumptions (due to lack of clarity in OP)**

- Min Value is optional
- If present, Min Value is succeeded by a "/", followed by Max Value
- Description is optional

Since OP haven't mentioned what to assume when Min Value is not available, I have used string type for Min/Max values, but should be ideally replaced by apt DataType.

```
public Sample Split(string columnValue)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"(?<min>\d+-)?(?<max>\d+)(?<unit>[\/a-zA-Z]+)\s?(\((?<description>(.+))\))?",RegexOptions.Compiled);
    var match = regex.Match(columnValue);
    if(match.Success)
    {
        return new Sample
        {
            Min = match.Groups["min"].Value,
            Max = match.Groups["max"].Value,
            Unit = match.Groups["unit"].Value,
            Description = match.Groups["description"].Value
        };
    }
    return default;
}

public class Sample
{
    public string Min{get;set;}
    public string Max{get;set;}
    public string Unit{get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
}
```

For Example,

```
var list = new []
    {
    @"974/mt (ICD TKD)",
    @"974/mt (+AD 91.27/mt, ICD/TKD)",
    @"970-980/mt",
    "970-980/mt"
    };

   foreach(var item in list)
   {
     var result = Split(item);
     Console.WriteLine($"Min={result.Min},Max={result.Max},Unit={result.Unit},Description={result.Description}");
   }
```

Output

```
Min=,Max=974,Unit=/mt,Description=ICD TKD
Min=,Max=974,Unit=/mt,Description=+AD 91.27/mt, ICD/TKD
Min=970-,Max=980,Unit=/mt,Description=
Min=970-,Max=980,Unit=/mt,Description=
```

Comment: @SumitSingh Glad it helped

Comment: hey @anu viswan suppose i have only single number eg:- 1235 and 1235-2568 with no unit and discription then itz not working for them.

Comment: @SumitSingh You could use something as following - "((?<min>\d+-)?(?<max>\d+)(?<unit>[\/a-zA-Z]+)\s?(\((?<description>(.+))\))?)|(?<minNumOnly>\d+-)?(?<maxnumOnly>\d+)"  - Please note I haven't tested it.

Comment: actuly i want that (eg:-1235) single minimum value in <min> and Range value should be like in <min> and <max>.